# code::block will keep flashing in taskbar when open it

Tags: codeblocks

After I clicked the code:: block icon, the code::block app icon kept flickering or flashing in the taskbar until the app was opened completely.

Comment: Which version of CodeBlocks and which OS are you using?

Comment: 20.03 and win11

Answer (score 0):

Flashing the icon in the task bar, while opening CodeBlocks, is not a problem that compromises the operation of the IDE. 
Is due to loading the wxWidgets libraries used by CodeBlocks.
The issue has been fixed in the developing version (Nightly builds).